# Why do Stripe CLI HttpPost webhook calls (events) to Asp.NET Core MVC Controller give "System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to integrate and test Stripe with my Asp.NET Core app using .NET Core 3.1, and every time a call is made to a webhook an exception is thrown.

This is the controller code:

```
 namespace Revoow.Controllers
{
[Route("webhooks")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class StripeWebhook : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PaymentService _service;
    private readonly string _webhookSecret;

    public StripeWebhook(IOptions<StripeOptions> options,
                         PaymentService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _webhookSecret = options.Value.WebhookSigningKey;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Api Post called");
        //string json = HttpContext.Request.Body;
        var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

        try
        {
            var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,
                Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], _webhookSecret);
            switch (stripeEvent.Type)
            {
                case Events.CustomerSourceUpdated:
                    //make sure payment info is valid
                    break;
                case Events.CustomerSourceExpiring:
                    //send reminder email to update payment method
                    break;
                case Events.ChargeFailed:
                    //do something
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (StripeException e)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stripe CLI console for listening:

```
    C:\Users\KW\Desktop>stripe listen --forward-to localhost:5001/webhooks
Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_RubNtLjCn5LViFW6TQ0uP3ObUnU4TRiC (^C to quit)
2020-05-20 22:31:40   --> customer.updated [evt_1Gl57xHB8f5ruaPfksEtJKAf]
2020-05-20 22:32:16            [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post http://localhost:5001/webhooks: EOF
```

Stripe CLI console for trigger events:

```
C:\Users\KW\Desktop>stripe trigger customer.created
Setting up fixture for: customer
Trigger succeeded! Check dashboard for event details.
```

And the error I get from Visual Studio debug console:

```
'Revoow.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.2\System.Net.Security.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

As you can see, the post method has the Debug.WriteLine("Api Post called") line which is never called, meaning that the error occurs before it gets to that.

The error messages are so basic they are of little help. Please help.

Comment: As you said, the exceptions are so generic it's hard to debug further. Could you try a couple things and update your question?

1. Remove all Stripe code from your async HttpPost method
2. Try to run a POST directly to http://localhost:5001/webhooks, rather than use the Stripe CLI.

It seems like this is happening more in the ASP.NET framework than in yours or Stripe's code, so hopefully we can narrow something down here.

Comment: @hpar I changed the code to only have " Debug.WriteLine("Post called"); return Ok(); and send an empty requst from Postman and get the same error

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting on a reply—since you removed the Stripe code from your request handler and are seeing the same error, this seems to point to some configuration issue in your ASP.NET build. Unfortunately, that's hard to debug. I might try starting from scratch with a blank ASP.NET, getting this working, and then attempting to update your existing app once you have a known-good solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the very same problem, what fixed it was to write https in the url i.e.

```
stripe listen --forward-to https://localhost:5001/webhooks
```

instead of:

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:5001/webhooks
```

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me. The Stripe documentation doesn't clearly show that.